# App Scope with Require AMD

Tags: javascript, requirejs, amd

So I've got a large site that includes a requirejs amd app as a standalone plugin rather than as the whole site application.  I'd like to be able to access methods within the plugin eg. App.initialize(); when an independent login button is pressed.  But, 'App' isn't attached to window.App.  Where is 'App' and or how can I attach App to the global namespace, so I can access it from disparate parts of the site?

Thanks!

Comment: If binding events through normal HTML attributes (which cannot utilize all the fun AMD-loaded modules) then an object *must* be exported into the global namespace so it can be accessed. Any code (within the AMD system/mindset) can, of course, just require the necessary `App` module and use that.

Comment: Ah, I see. So I simply export App like this window.App = App; in the main module where App is defined.  Works!  Thanks.

Comment: Cool :) Just be aware that the "main module" *might* be loaded asynchronously, depending upon how it is setup. Because of this, I keep my *must be synchronous* modules/libraries out of AMD and loaded via normal script elements - hopefully these are pretty rare, but I count jQuery and such in the list. (They have AMD stubs/shims so that they can be used in AMD, but they also contribute to the global pollution - what a nice what to put it! - before AMD even takes over.)